# Deleting a record in a table MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

Im having some trouble when I try to delete a record from a table. I get the error:

The number of primary key values passed must match number of primary key values defined on the entity.

The table has a composite primary key. They are cabinCrewId and flightId.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Delete(string name)
    {
         using (A1Context db = new A1Context())
         {
             var id = from person in db.person
                      from flightcabincrew in db.flightcabincrew
                      from cabincrew in db.cabincrew
                      where person.name == name
                      where person.id == cabincrew.person
                      where cabincrew.person == flightcabincrew.cabinCrewId
                      select new { flightcabincrew.cabinCrewId, flightcabincrew.flightId };

             FlightCabinCrew fcc = db.flightcabincrew.Find(id);
             if (fcc == null)
             {
                 return HttpNotFound();
             }
             else
             {
                 return View(fcc);
             }
         }
    }
```

Post:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(FlightCabinCrew fcc)
    {
        using (A1Context db = new A1Context())
        {
            db.Entry(fcc).State = System.Data.EntityState.Deleted;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return View();
    }
```

and part of the view concerned:

```
  @model IEnumerable<Assignment2.Models.FlightCrewGrid>
        @{
            WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model);
        }
        <h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
        @grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("PersonName", "Crew Member"),
            grid.Column("FlightDay", "Flight Day"),
            grid.Column("FromAirport", "From"),
            grid.Column("ToAirport", "To"),
            grid.Column("Model", "Model"),
            grid.Column("startDate", "Start Date"),
            grid.Column(header: "Delete", format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.PersonName})))
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't declare a primary key for the entity. You do this by marking the primary key column with the `[Key]` attribute.

```
[Key]
public int cabinCrewId { get; set; }

[Key]
public int flightId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I do have that set in my model [Key][Column(Order = 1)] for the first and Oreder = 2 for the second.

Answer (score 0):

public ActionResult Demodelete(int id)

```
    {
        Employee emptbl = new Employee();
        emptbl.EmpId = id;
        dbc.Entry(emptbl).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        dbc.SaveChanges();

        return View();
    }
```